# subplots within subplots - two 8x8 subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create subplot within two subplots to display images of different sizes.

The main figure will be divided into two plots -- and each of those plots will
be further divided into 8x8 subplots. I don't want any axes displayed.

So I will have two subplots, displaying 64 images (64 subplots) each.

It seems I need to use gridspec, but I don't know how to use axes.flatten with 
gridspec.  axes.flatten lets me display 64 images onto one figure.

```
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)

gs00 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(8, 8, subplot_spec=gs0[0])
gs01 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(8, 8, subplot_spec=gs0[1])
```

I don't know how to combine the code below with gridspec, to create
subplots.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=8,figsize = (12,6))

  for ax,image in zip(axes.flat,images):
            ax.axes.set_axis_off()
            ax.imshow(imread(image))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: you don't

`pyplot.subplots` is a top-level function and its main purpose is convenience.

You're gonna have to go a little, but not much, deeper into the API for what you want.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import gridspec

fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(24, 12))

gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
gs00 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(8, 8, subplot_spec=gs0[0])
gs01 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(8, 8, subplot_spec=gs0[1])

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        ax00 = fig.add_subplot(gs00[i, j])
        ax00.text(0.5, 0.5, '0_{}_{}'.format(i, j), ha='center')
        ax00.set_xticks([])
        ax00.set_yticks([])

        ax01 = fig.add_subplot(gs01[i, j])
        ax01.text(0.5, 0.5, '1_{}_{}'.format(i, j), ha='center')
        ax01.set_xticks([])
        ax01.set_yticks([])
```

[image]

Note that if you're plotting a lot of images, the axes_grid1 toolkit might be useful:

http://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/axes_grid.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-toolkits-axes-grid-py

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for the additional resource - going to take a look at it.

Comment: @Paul_H  (How do you ping some who has a space in between their username?).   Hi. I just have a simple question. Is there a way to add titles to the two main subplots? `Image set 1' to the left, `Image set 2` to the right subplot. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Moondra I would use `fig.text` http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=figure%20text#matplotlib.figure.Figure.text